# How to disable scrolling ViewPager while keyboard is shown?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app and use ViewPager inside it. It scrolls fragments, one of which contains the text input field. So the problem is the following: while the keyboard is showing I still can scroll fragments. have anybody met the same problem?

This is my Main Activity code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the fragment code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.Login">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loginLogo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/logo_foreground"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loginUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="15"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginLogo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="15"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginUsername"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/loginPassword"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Войти" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was solved the next way: I just created a little function to hide the keyboard

```
 public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

And then used the listener of ViewPager:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            hideKeyboard(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (prevMenuItem != null)
                prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            else
                 navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);

            navigation.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
            prevMenuItem = navigation.getMenu().getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```